# Why are faithful actions called faithful and who first called them faithful?

Tags: terminology, lie-groups, math-history, group-actions

I want to know *why* are faithful actions called faithful and *who* first called them  faithful?

**Definition:** An action $G$ on $X$ is faithful when ${g_1 \neq g_2  \Rightarrow  g_1 x \neq g_2 x}$ for some ${x \in X}$ (different elements of $G$ act differently at some point).

Comment: good question (+$1$); I always remembered faithful as reliable that no two group elements act the same on all set elements, otherwise there wouldn't be a reason to have two different group elements in the context of their action, but I don't really know

Comment: +1: good question, but you might do better on https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359121/why-is-faithful-actions-called-faithful-and-who-first-called-it-faithful

Comment: and in fact is comprehensively answered on MO, as per Gerry's link.